# emv pin change operation without second card authorization

Tags: emv

What if the second card authorization fails in a pin change operation?

Is executing a script without a second card authorization acceptable? Do we have to roll back operations ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't revert anything with a card. You just go step by step by the spec, send commands to the card in proper sequence, analyse the card responses and set appropriate bits in `TVR`.

The `Pin Change/Unlock` command in a script is protected with a `Message Authentication Code` that card must verify before applying the change and reject a command if `MAC` check fails.

Also, I hardly could imagine that a modern issuer would send a pin-change script without `Issuer Authentication Data`. So the `Generate AC` is unlikely to fail if an `External Authenticate` and `Pin Change` successfully processed by a card.

Even if the issuer does not support the Issuer Authentication, you just strictly follow the spec: you check the command execution status and take the action according to the spec.

All other things are beyond the EMV spec. Thus, the Payment System may require the `TC` to be always delivered to the Issuer (online or as part of a batch tx upload).